# Clicking through an Array to Load a Configuration

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am implementing a way for the user to be able to load a configuration they have created. The Application is a 3D Model Product Configurator. The model is created by clicking numerous elements on the web page which alter the appearance of the model.

I will explain the flow of what happens.

The clicks of the html elements are pushed to an array and send to the database upon the user clicking save. They can also provide their build with a name.

Converting Array from JavaScript to PHP

```
var array = [];
$('img').click(function(){

var id = $(this).attr('id');
array.push(id);
});

//Post Test
 $('#save').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var buildName = "GRP 120x120x90 - " + 
document.getElementById("buildName").value;


$.ajax({
  url:"readJsonSave.php",
  method: "post",
  data: { array: JSON.stringify( array ), buildName: JSON.stringify(buildName) },
  success: function(res){
  console.log(res);
  }
})
});
```

ReadJsonSave.php File

```
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
global $wpdb;
global $current_user;

$table_name= $wpdb->prefix. 'product_configurator';
$DBP_buildName =   wp_unslash( $_POST['buildName'] );
$DBP_buildConfig = wp_unslash( $_POST['array'] );
$enclosure = "120x120x90";
$user_id = get_current_user_id();



$wpdb->insert($table_name,
  array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'user_name' => $user_login,
        'user_email' => $user_email,
        'enclosure_type' => $enclosure,
        'keymap_key' => $DBP_buildName,
        'key_map' => $DBP_buildConfig
  ),
  array(
    '%s', //use for string format
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s'
  )
)
```

To Load the Array The user is presented first with their "build names" they chose when saving a configuration.

```
  <?php 

    global $wpdp;
    global $current_user;

      $table_name= $wpdb->prefix. 'product_configurator';
        $DBP_results= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE user_id = $current_user->ID");
        $DBP_current_user = get_current_user_id();
  ?>

    <?php foreach($DBP_results as $DBP_cols){
        $user_id= $DBP_cols->user_id;
        $enclosure_type= $DBP_cols->enclosure_type;
        $keymap_key= json_decode($DBP_cols->keymap_key, true);
        $key_map=json_decode($DBP_cols->key_map, true);

     ?>
     <div class="load" id="loader"+ i><?php print_r($keymap_key); ?></div>

   <?php } ?>
```

Once a build is clicked the following code gets the innerhtml of the div and places it into a javascript variable and passes it over to php to be matched against in the database query.

```
var i=0;
$('.load').each(function(){
i++;
var newID='loader'+i;
$(this).attr('id',newID);
$(this).val(i);
});

$('#loader1').click(function(){

$("#loader1").addClass("loadSelect");
var loadDump = document.getElementById("loader1").innerHTML;
console.log(loadDump);

 $.ajax({
  url:"load.php",
  method: "post",
  data: { loadDump: JSON.stringify( loadDump )},
  success: function(res){
  console.log(res);

  }
})


})
```

Finally the load.php where the query is searched for and matched. How can i now use the array $key_map_loaded and fire a click function that will click each item in the array to make the changes on the front end.

```
$loadDump =   wp_unslash( $_POST['loadDump'] );
print_r($loadDump);


      $table_name= $wpdb->prefix. 'product_configurator';
        $DBP_results= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE 
        keymap_key = $loadDump");
        $DBP_current_user = get_current_user_id();


     foreach($DBP_results as $DBP_cols){
        $user_id= $DBP_cols->user_id;
        $enclosure_type= $DBP_cols->enclosure_type;
        $keymap_key= json_decode($DBP_cols->keymap_key, true);
        $key_map_loaded=json_decode($DBP_cols->key_map, true);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you REALLY should see [`wp_ajax_{action}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) and [`wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) for ajax requests in Wordpres.

For your problem, I don't really see where and why you are stuck. Because, you made the hardest work already (JS => PHP), give resulsts to JS is really simple because it can only really read JSON (in an ajax answer).

So, in PHP, when a configuration is loaded (by clicking on #loader1) you made your AJAX request, and simply header JSON encoded response with the good constructed object and echo it by json_encode()

Here is my function to echo JSON Responses in PHP :

```
function json_response($response = null)
{
    // End AJAX return if no data.
    if ($response == null)
        exit;
    // Proper headers for json output.
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // Output our response.
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

**NB:** You can also add `dataType` param to [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method but it's always better to have the right header ;-)

Comment: im struggling with the last section. In the Load.php, i cant seem to get the array back into javascript. Working in the load.php file i have the following code                      <script type='text/javascript'>
var array_code = <?php echo $key_map_loaded; ?>;
console.log(array_code);
</script>
but this just logs the code and not the array when its ran

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand. All you have to do is create an array that you can easily loop in javascript. For example :

```
['a' => true, 'b' => true, 'c' => false]
```

json_encode() your array for your ajax response. In javascript, just loop the array. If we admit our keys are ids of each checkbox :

```
// Since "v" is true/false in our example
// the code is prety straightforward
$.each(json_response, function(k, v) { 
   $('#'+k).prop('checked', v); 
});
```

A more complete snippet :

```
$('body').on('click', '.config-loader', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'load.php',
        data: {
            action: 'load_configuration',
            nonce: 'randomized_nonce_for_security',
            config_id: $this.data('config-id'),
        },
        success: function(json_response) {
            $.each(json_response, function(k, v) { 
               $('#'+k).prop('checked', v); 
            });
        }
    });
});
```